# 'The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed' - after adding Dispose()

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, web-applications

I am getting the above error on various controller actions after adding the line....

```
protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            repo.Dispose();
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
```

...to my controller. Before adding this line I had an issue with the DbContext returning old or cached data after a record update operation. Now that seems to be fixed, but I'm having 'DbContext has been disposed' issue. My controller looks like this...

```
public class CasesToReviewController : Controller
    {
        private CaseReviewRepository repo;

        public CasesToReviewController()
        {
            repo = new CaseReviewRepository(DataAccess.Current);
        }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
            {
                repo.Dispose();
                base.Dispose(disposing);
            }
    }
```

Repository looks like this...

```
 public class CaseReviewRepository : IDisposable
    {
        private HSADBContext _db;

        public CaseReviewRepository(HSADBContext db)
        {
            _db = db;
        }

private bool disposed = false;

        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (!this.disposed)
            {
                if (disposing)
                {
                    _db.Dispose();
                }
            }
            this.disposed = true;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }
    }
```

DataAccess.Current is a Ninject binding. I'm not sure how much of it I can post because it's not my code, but it seems to work fine in other Controllers for the project I'm working on, and the change in errors after adding the Dispose() function to the contoller makes me think this is an issue with the way I implemented IDispoable.

Stepping through with debugger I see that the context is getting disposed *between* the time that it is created in the Controller constructor and that time that the repository method is actually entered. Like when execution leaves scope of controller context is disposed. Is this how Dispose() method works? And if so do I need to remove Dispose() implementation from my constructor?

Comment: Have you tried calling in the opposite order (meaning `base.Dispose` before `this.Dispose`)?

Comment: Are you returning entity objects out of a method, after disposing the data context used to fetch them?

Comment: Honestly I don't really understand *when* exactly dispose is called, and when the context is disposed. The offending repository calls are mostly returning IEnumerable<SomeModel>

Comment: Like for instance I don't understand why you need a Dispose() implementation in the Controller AND the repository it uses

Comment: @evanmcdonnal - No, that didn't fix it